# Permisssion denied on rw NFS share

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs

With an NFS share mounted using `mount server_hostname:/srv/home /mnt -o rw,sync`, I'm getting `Permission denied` errors when trying to write (even as root). The server's `/etc/exports` looks like this:

```
/srv/home 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

It's definitely mounted as `rw` (I checked in the output of `mount`), but I'm not able to write.

Server is running Ubuntu, client running Arch.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I wasn't able to write as root because I didn't have `no_root_squash` set on the share.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED - sorry for the prior answer, you are correct, should have been a comment.

Might want to check your UIDs between the systems, we have seen issues where user accounts with different UIDs that don't exist on one or the other machine could not write to mounts on other machines.  I would think you would need known user accounts, with identical uid values, between the systems to read/write to shares between the two.  I am pretty positive that is the case in our mixed network at my current place of business, and I *assume* that is a likely need in any mixed network.

Comment: I've updated the question with more info - this answer should probably be a comment though.

Comment: I'm not able to write as root (aka. UID 0), which I _definitely_ should be